# Is it possible to grow a nose on a human forehead?

Tags: medical-science

I have seen a few articles now reporting that a Chinese doctor has actually grown a second nose on his patient's forehead:

- [LA Times](http://www.latimes.com/science/sciencenow/la-sci-sn-doctor-builds-nose-forehead-20130926,0,4557555.story)
- [Business Insider](http://www.businessinsider.com/chinese-man-grows-new-nose-on-forehead-2013-9)
- [USA Today](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2013/09/25/china-transplant-nose-forehead/2871369/)
- [ABC News](http://abcnews.go.com/blogs/health/2013/09/25/doctors-grow-nose-on-mans-forehead/)

While many of these can be considered "reputable" news sources,  there have been times they've gotten it really wrong.  I'm curious if there has even been an research or verified successes done in this area that actually support these claims.

Comment: Hint: if you value your sanity, do not, I repeat, *do not* google for pictures of “teratoma”. But that’s it: tumours that grow (incomplete) organs. Like hair. Or teeth. Or eyes. Or indeed noses.

Comment: @KonradRudolph What about brains?

Comment: @JAB Not brains. Too specifically controlled during embryo development. Though, who knows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [National Geographic](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2013/09/130928-nose-forehead-ear-arm-reconstructive-surgery-medical-science/):

> It's called prelamination: Tissue that's going to be used to rebuild an area is constructed in multiple layers.
>
> Take the nose, for example. If the damage from disease or injury goes all the way through, then all three layers must be replaced: the skin on the outside, the cartilage, and the soft lining inside. The forehead skin tends to be the best match for the outside skin from an area called the paramedian forehead flap...

It's not "grown" on the forehead, but rather, "constructed". While the nose is being constructed on the forehead, it does not get connected to the normal air passages. After the nose is constructed, it is moved to its final destination where a nose normally would go, and connected with the normal air passages.

This technique also been performed using the forearm (Sinha et al. 2008) (includes pictures of the procedure). They also say that "a forehead flap, traditionally, has been the workhorse of such reconstructions and can provide excellent nasal reconstruction", but that "an adherent forehead scar precluded the use of a forehead flap".

The standard technique (using the forehead) is described in (Menick 2008, at p. 329).

#### References

Menick, Frederick J. Nasal reconstruction: art and practice. Elsevier Health Sciences, 2008.

Sinha, M., J. R. Scott, and S. B. Watson. "Prelaminated free radial forearm flap for a total nasal reconstruction." Journal of Plastic, Reconstructive & Aesthetic Surgery 61, no. 8 (2008): 953-957.